# Routing strategy in react native using stack navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, mobx

I am new to react native and using stack navigator to for routing from React navigation.

But I have one issue which is more about my routing architecture.
My Doubt :
After completing the one action , I need to move to next screen. But I do not know what should be the next screen. For this I make server call of an api ..and on the basis of the response I decide next screen.

But this same api I again need to call on every screen when its opened to keep my state in sync with server state.

Right now I am doing the above approach and using Mobx.

I want to know..if there are any good or optimise pattern or architecture to handle this situation.

I looked for solution from online..but I am stuck on architecture part.